# How to jump on current page on dropdown selection changed event with the help of datapager and listview?

Tags: asp.net

There is dropdown and datapager in my page. On the event of dropdown data is being populated in listview.Since there is datapager in my page user can jump from one page to another. That's fine.

But my question is that if currently the user in second page and if user selection from dropdown then datapager jump to the first page.

How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DataPager class has a cryptically named method called SetPageProperties. You can use this to reset the page number. e.g. `pager.SetPageProperties( 0, pager.PageSize, true )`.